# Blazor JS interop with Typescript - proper DotNet declaration import

Tags: typescript, blazor, tsconfig

I'm writing a Razor Class Library that incorporates JavaScript interop transpiled from TypeScript. Some code in TypeScript will reference globally available variable `DotNet` which gets included when Blazor libraries are initialized. I was able to find `DotNet` module declaration in `@microsoft/dotnet-js-interop` Node package (added as devDependency) and TypeScript is able to find the export when `"moduleResolution": "node"` is set in my `tsconfig.json`. However, if I do `import { DotNet } from "@microsoft/dotnet-js-interop"`, then this import is kept in transpiled JavaScript code. I tried a few workarounds, but they didn't work:

1. Using `import type { DotNet } from "@microsoft/dotnet-js-interop"` results in `(TS) 'DotNet' cannot be used as a value because it was imported using 'import type'.` wherever `DotNet` is being referenced;
2. I cannot for my life get any results when trying things like `///<reference types/path="@microsoft/dotnet-js-interop or node_modules/@microsoft/dotnet-js-interop/dist/Microsoft.JSInterpop.d.ts">` or modifying `tsconfig.json` values such as `paths` (with `"baseUrl"="."`) or `typeRoots`. All theses result in error `(TS) Cannot find name 'DotNet'`.

Is there any way to properly import `DotNet` module declaration without polluting transpiled JavaScript code with unnecessary imports?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was tricky (lack of cohesive documentation didn't help), but I was able to figure it out myself.

The trick is to declare a variable and define its type with `typeof import` like so:

```
declare const DotNet: typeof import("@microsoft/dotnet-js-interop").DotNet;
```

Put this at the top of a file and you're good to go.